# How to disable interface suggestions in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I.E Global browser interfaces keep showing up while editing .js files and therefore distracting my work?

Answer (score -1):

This was a bug in VSCode <=1.13: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15750

It should be fixed in VSCode 1.14+. Please let us know if you still see this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: 1.14 should be out next week. Until then, try the insiders build: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders

Comment: Interfaces are still there. Using the latest version of VSC

Comment: Which interfaces? We still show interfaces if they are for types that can be instantiated

Comment: [screen](https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAaDUQnv67wJdqPTLT8hXosM2JRpGoOdQc8W-J_mGHPDA/12/193818619/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/vscode.png/EMifgZMBGPfbFyAHKAc/r9d0kzX7ZYX11eWdx3CI9HqRFOvGA1V9c65b7I8HwiQ?size=1280x960&size_mode=3) Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Getting a 403 on the image. It may be better if you open a bug on github: http://github.com/vscode/issues/new